# Django filter().first() returning different result than get()

Tags: python, django, filter, model, django-queryset

I can't figure out how to debug this. I have this Django model:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# ...

class AbstractPhrase(models.Model):
    term2_past_tense = models.TextField(_('term 2 past tense'))
    # ... other simple fields and methods

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class CommentPhrase(AbstractPhrase, models.Model):
    """A phrase that comprises part of a report card comment"""
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='phrases')

    old_id = models.CharField(
        _('old ID'),
        max_length=10,
        blank=True,
        null=True)

    # ... Other simple fields

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('skill', 'question_number')
        verbose_name = _('comment phrase')
        verbose_name_plural = _('comment phrases')
```

An administrator reported that the model couldn't be updated in the Django admin. After saving, the Django admin would report that the model updated successfully, but when they refreshed the page the data was still out of date.

I opened up a Django shell and investigate:

```
In [3]: cp = CommentPhrase.objects.get(pk=10280)

In [4]: cp
Out[4]: <CommentPhrase: lorem ipsum>

In [5]: cp.term2_past_tense
Out[5]: ''

In [6]: cp.term2_past_tense = "Test"

In [7]: cp.save()

In [8]: cp.term2_past_tense
Out[8]: 'Test'

In [9]: cp.refresh_from_db()

In [10]: cp.term2_past_tense
Out[10]: ''
```

I further tried doing a queryset update(), and this had the same result.

It got weirder when I looked in the database. It turns out the value was actually successfully updated in the postgres shell. I could see the updated values with this syntax:

```
In [7]: CommentPhrase.objects.filter(pk=10280).first().term2_past_tense
Out[7]: 'Test'
```

But not with this:

```
In [12]: CommentPhrase.objects.get(pk=10280).term2_past_tense
Out[12]: ''
```

Count returns 1:

```
In [2]: CommentPhrase.objects.filter(pk=10280).count()
Out[2]: 1
```

So why on earth would filter(pk=x).first() return something different than get(pk=x) ???

I can see that on the raw database, the value is there, but it doesn't show up for get, and it doesn't show up in the Django admin.

There are hundreds of instances in the database that have been maintained and updated through imports and exports and the Django admin over the years. It has just recently stopped working. I've confirmed that migrations are up to date and consistent between both production and local, and the database schema looks good from a manual inspection.

On my local machine all works well. The bug only appears on production. I am using

- Python 3.9.0
- Django 3.1.3
- psycopg2-binary 2.8.6

My local machine is using psql (PostgreSQL) 12.6 (Ubuntu 12.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) (Things are working here)
Production is using psql (11.6 (Ubuntu 11.6-1.pgdg18.04+1), server 10.15) on AWS RDS

Here is my cache config:

```py
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': '{0}/{1}'.format(env('REDIS_URL', default='redis://127.0.0.1:6379'), 0),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
            'IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS': True,  # mimics memcache behavior.
                                        # http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_memcached_exceptions_behavior
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There might be some db caching involved. You used `get()` to retrieve the initial Python object, and that result might still be returned during the same transaction. Try closing/restarting the shell after the update (`save()`).

Comment: @schwobaseggl I've closed/restarted the shell, as well as done `refresh_from_db()`. get is still returning none, and filter/first is still returning a result

Comment: Updated question to show Cache config

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. My redis cache service was not working at all, and I needed to restart the service. After the cache infrastructure was working, it was all good.